# Wrong number or types of arguments in call when running stored procedure which uses nested tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm having trouble running my stored procedure as it returns this error. I have checked the values and all seem to be correct data type so I'm unsure why it's not executing when the procedure is called. I'm aware you can create separate procedures for what I'm doing, but the task I've been set it requires to use nested tables.

Error

```
ORA-06550: line 19, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ORDER_ITEM'
ORA-06550: line 6, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Table and Types

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE order_item AS object(
      order_item_id INT,
    order_id INT, 
    product_id INT,
    seller_id INT, 
    sub_order_number CHAR(10),
    quantity INT, 
    condition CHAR(100),
    unit_price NUMBER, 
    cost_charge NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE order_items AS Table of order_item;
/

CREATE TABLE Orders (
 order_id INT CONSTRAINT PKEY_order PRIMARY KEY,
 order_number CHAR(10),
 billing_name CHAR(100),
 billing_email CHAR(100),
 billing_address VARCHAR2(100),
 billing_city VARCHAR2(100),
 billing_province VARCHAR2(100),
 billing_postcode VARCHAR2(100),
 billing_telephone NUMBER(25),
 billing_total NUMBER,
 order_date DATE,
 Items order_items)
 Nested Table Items Store As Orders_Item
/
```

Stored Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_new_order
(
    p_order_id IN INT, 
    p_order_num IN CHAR,
    p_name IN CHAR,
    p_email IN CHAR,
    p_address IN VARCHAR2, 
    p_city IN VARCHAR2,
    p_province IN VARCHAR2,
    p_postcode IN VARCHAR2,
    p_telephone IN NUMBER, 
    p_total IN NUMBER,
    p_order_date IN DATE,
    -- Order items
    p_order_item_id IN INT, 
    p_product_id IN INT, 
    p_seller_id IN INT,
    p_sub_order_number IN CHAR, 
    p_quantity IN INT,
    p_condition IN CHAR, 
    p_unit_price IN NUMBER, 
    p_cost_charge IN NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert attempted');

    INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, order_number, billing_name, billing_email, billing_address, billing_city, billing_province, billing_postcode, billing_telephone, billing_total, order_date, items)
    VALUES (p_order_id, p_order_num, p_name, p_email, p_address, p_city, p_province, p_postcode, p_telephone, p_total, p_order_date, order_items(
        order_item(p_order_item_id, p_order_id, p_product_id, p_seller_id, p_sub_order_number, p_quantity, p_condition, p_unit_price, p_cost_charge)));

    COMMIT;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert succeeded');

    EXCEPTION
     WHEN others THEN   
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert rejected');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Error Code:  ' || SQLCODE);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Error Message:  ' || SQLERRM); 
      ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

When trying to call the procedure.

```
DECLARE
  order_id_ NUMBER;
BEGIN
  order_id_ := 2;

  insert_new_order(
    p_order_id => order_id_,
    p_order_num => 'O223PS56',
    p_name => 'Test',
    p_email => 'test@test.co.uk',
    p_address => 'test@test.co.uk',
    p_city => 'Newcastle Upon Tyne',
    p_province => 'County Durham',
    p_postcode => 'Tyne and Wear',
    p_telephone => '123456789',
    p_total => 112.95,
    p_order_date => to_date('11-apr-2021', 'DD-mon-YYYY'),
    order_items(    
      order_item(
        p_order_item_id => 5, 
        order_id_,
        p_product_id => 2, 
        p_seller_id => 2, 
        p_sub_order_number => 3073748222, 
        p_quantity => 2, 
        p_condition => 'Brand New', 
        p_unit_price => 53.49,
        p_cost_charge => 0),
      order_item(
        p_order_item_id => 6, 
        order_id_,
        p_product_id => 1, 
        p_seller_id => 1, 
        p_sub_order_number => 3073748223, 
        p_quantity => 2, 
        p_condition => 'Brand New', 
        p_unit_price => 1.99, 
        p_cost_charge => 1.99)
      )
  );
END;
/
```

Comment: sub_order_number is  char(10) , and you give a number.  And are you sure of the p_-prefix?

Comment: The prefix is correct I wrapped quotes around the number and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to pass all the components of each `order_item`; just pass the array:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_new_order
(
    p_order_id    IN ORDERS.ORDER_ID%TYPE, 
    p_order_num   IN ORDERS.ORDER_NUMBER%TYPE,
    p_name        IN ORDERS.BILLING_NAME%TYPE,
    p_email       IN ORDERS.BILLING_EMAIL%TYPE,
    p_address     IN ORDERS.BILLING_ADDRESS%TYPE,
    p_city        IN ORDERS.BILLING_CITY%TYPE,
    p_province    IN ORDERS.BILLING_PROVINCE%TYPE,
    p_postcode    IN ORDERS.BILLING_POSTCODE%TYPE,
    p_telephone   IN ORDERS.BILLING_TELEPHONE%TYPE, 
    p_total       IN ORDERS.BILLING_TOTAL%TYPE,
    p_order_date  IN ORDERS.ORDER_DATE%TYPE,
    p_items       IN ORDERS.ITEMS%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert attempted');

    INSERT INTO Orders (
      order_id,
      order_number,
      billing_name,
      billing_email,
      billing_address,
      billing_city,
      billing_province,
      billing_postcode,
      billing_telephone,
      billing_total,
      order_date,
      items
    ) VALUES (
      p_order_id,
      p_order_num,
      p_name,
      p_email,
      p_address,
      p_city,
      p_province,
      p_postcode,
      p_telephone,
      p_total,
      p_order_date,
      p_items
    );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert succeeded');
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  order_id_ NUMBER;
BEGIN
  order_id_ := 2;

  insert_new_order(
    p_order_id => order_id_,
    p_order_num => 'O223PS56',
    p_name => 'Test',
    p_email => 'test@test.co.uk',
    p_address => 'test@test.co.uk',
    p_city => 'Newcastle Upon Tyne',
    p_province => 'County Durham',
    p_postcode => 'Tyne and Wear',
    p_telephone => '123456789',
    p_total => 112.95,
    p_order_date => to_date('11-apr-2021', 'DD-mon-YYYY'),
    p_items => order_items(    
      order_item(5, order_id_, 2, 2, 3073748222, 2, 'Brand New', 53.49, 0),
      order_item(6, order_id_, 1, 1, 3073748223, 2, 'Brand New',  1.99, 1.99)
    )
  );
  
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

*(Note: Do not `COMMIT` in your procedure as you want to be able to call the procedure multiple times and choose whether to `COMMIT` them as a batch or `ROLLBACK` as a batch. Also, do not catch the `OTHERS` error as it will mask a lot of issues and make debugging very difficult. If you want to catch specific errors then catch those specific errors only and let the other errors propagate so you know what needs debugging; there will be an implicit `ROLLBACK` in the case when an exception is raised so you do not need to explicitly do that.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0d5632304ee8bb268988c0a3942f6b5f)*

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot sense, will do really appreciate the help.

Comment: Didn't know that number to char conversion(sub_order_number) is done implicitly